# Render a partial view from an action within another area

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net MVC project that is split into 'areas'

On a view in area 'A' I wish to render a partial view via a controller within area 'B'.

I have the following within my View inside area 'A'

```
Html.RenderAction("Index", "AreaBHome", new { Area="AreaB"});
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this

```
 Html.RenderAction("action", "controller", new { area = "Area", model = ViewData.Model })..
```

or this

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/ControllerName/_PartialView.cshtml", Model)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am unsure which 'Model' I am meant to pass though.

Comment: @jjc99 ...either use the **@model keyword** in your partial view which states which model you need to pass or use **null** when you use stuff like ViewBag, ViewData, ...

Comment: Note that the `@Html.Partial(...)` form does not call the corresponding controller.